# Ubuntu Firmware for Meizu MX4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, migration, firmware, meizu-mx4

I own a Meizu MX4 device with Flyme Firmware on it...

I'm interested if there is a way to get and flash Ubuntu on it, because I would really like to try new Ubuntu OS?

Thnx!